# While archiving my application I'm getting Error for Realm

Tags: ios, realm, xcode10, swift4.2

I archive my application and now want upload to app store.

When I validate it or upload this error occurred :

> Code signing "Realm.framework" failed

Comment: This is my Log report "Realm.framework: code object is not signed at all" 2018-09-21 13:16:00 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but for anyone else facing this issue here's how I solved it.

I had dragged the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks into my project manually. When I deleted those frameworks and installed Realm through Cocoapods the error went away.

If you must have the framework manually installed in your project, go to the General tab of the framework and make sure the team is set to None.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using realm by carthage, if this is the case don't forget to add the script to the Build phase:

> On your application target’s “Build Phases” settings tab, click the
>   “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script with
>   the following contents:
>
> `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks` and add the
>   paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:
>
> Copy to
>   `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework`
>   This script works around an App Store submission bug triggered by
>   universal binaries.

[Source](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

Very important the order of the script must be below `Embed framework`:

[image]